# Dealing with Dependencies when instantiating MVC objects in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I know that's not the most amazing title in the world, but bear with me.
I'm developing an application in Java, for part of which I'm using the MVC design pattern.

[image: UML]

Above is my understanding of the MVC structure, or at least how I'm choosing to implement it. However I've run into a problem instantiating the objects. Since any given **controller** requires a reference to it's **view** pair, and any given **view** requires a reference to it's **controller** pair, I'm not sure how to actually create the objects.

I could pass the view into the controller as null and then immediately set it, but not only does this feel like bad coding practice it raised questions about where I actually should be creating the view. Is it something normally delegated to the controller? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why should a view know its controller? In fact, it introduces another coupling that is not wanted. Instead, in the view you can simply react to model changes via the observer pattern (like you sketched). If you really need to react to controller events, you can use the observer pattern here, too. This is what AWT and Swing do (btw) with the [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html).

Comment: Also, have a look at the following picture: https://manikandanmv.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/mvc-architecture.gif?w=450&h=315. The described _events_ are usually implemented via the observer pattern.

Comment: Ah okay, after reading around a bit I think I'm going to incorporate the View and Controler classes together, because that seems to be a common way to deal with swing and MVC. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass one as a constructor parameter to the other like this:

```
public class Controller {
    private View view;

    public Controller() {
        this.view = new View(this);
    }
}

public class View {
    private Controller controller;

    public View(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
}
```